# Python - Update Dictionary With User Input

Tags: python, dictionary

For this part of my program, I need to write code that will allow the user to update the dictionary. The key is the employee ID, and the updatable fields are their name, department, and title. So that when the updated record is viewed it would display the new name, title, and department. Where Employees is the dictionary. This is what i have so far:

```
while Choice == '2':

    dict_key = input('Enter the employee ID of the employee to change the record: ')

    if dict_key in Employees:
        n = 3
        print('Enter the new Name, Department, and Title')
        for i in range(n):
            updates = input().split(' ')

        Employees[dict_key] = updates[0][1][2]          
        print('\n')
    else:
        print('ERROR: That record does not exist!')
        print('\n')

    Continue = input('Press 1 to update another employee record or 2 to exit: ')
    print('\n')

    if Continue == '2':
        print('*' * 80)
        break
```

When running this code i get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
line 43, in <module>
  Employees[dict_key] = updates[0][1][2]
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Desired output for ex:
If employee ID 1234 = John,IT,Programmer
and the updates were: John Doe, IT, Manager.

Employee ID 1234 should = John Doe,IT,Manager after the update entries.

**Edit** 
I was trying to program this in a way where the user could enter the updates individually (name first, title second..) and update the dictionary for the key value (1234) with all three inputs to get my desired output.

Sorry if my code is a mess, I am learning python at the moment. Also sorry if my post is a mess, first time here as well.

Comment: if updates contained `,` then you should `split(',')`; also, you're overwriting `updates` in the for loop

Comment: You are not doing what you think you're doing.  `updates[0]` will get you the first string (`"John Doe"`), then `updates[0][1]` will give you `"J"`, and finally `updates[0][1][2]` gives you an `IndexError` because `[2]` goes beyond the end of the string.  If you mean to store the data as a tuple, then simply using `Employees[dict_key] = updates` will do the trick.  I think what you really meant to do was `updates[0], updates[1], updates[2]`). Note: there are other issues with your approach and splitting. You should ask for each field individually (name, department, title) and avoid splitting.

Answer (score 1):

You .split method isn't working, as the user isn't inputting any spaces (' '). Instead change your code to `updates = input().split(',')`

that should fix one of the issues

Answer (score 0):

The `updates` is a list. If you want to store the updated records, you should write as:

```
Employee[dict_key] = updates
```

This will create a structure:

```
{'1234': ['John', 'IT', 'Manager']}
```

Also as pointed by the comments, if the input is separated by `,` then use `split(',')`

Answer (score 0):

Your `updates` is a list with one string which you erase with each new input in your `for` loop over n . You may want to use `append` to add new elements in your list.

So your `for` loop will be

```
for i in range(n):
            updates.append(input().split(' '))
```

After having defined updates as a list, earlier in the code.
Plus, using `split` will make your `updates` be a list of lists :

```
>>> updates
>>> [['John'], ['IT'], ['programmer']]
```

I suggest you to write `updates.append(input())` then the output will be `['John', 'IT', 'programmer']`

Finally to access those new information, you just have to consider updates as a 1D list.

Hope this is helpful

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I feel a bit dumb. But I managed to figure out my problem. After reading the comments my light bulb came on. I made an empty list, and appended each input to the list. To allow for the three separate inputs.

```
updates = []

        updates.append(input('Enter the new name: '))
        updates.append(input('Enter the new department: '))
        updates.append(input('Enter the new Title: '))
```

I also updated this portion to:

```
Employees[dict_key] = updates
```

And now my output is as follows after updating:

```
['John Doe', 'IT', 'Manager']
```

Thank y'all for the feedback! I don't know why I did not think of that earlier.